# HTML Dropdown disappears after a value is set to null in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have two values `power` and `mainPower` which describe the same thing but `mainPower` saves an id of type `Long` in the backend and `power` saves all attributes of this dto. With the code below I can update a hero's power, meaning I can change it from something to the other and also make it `null` (meaning no power).

The problem is that when a power is set to `null` or it was `null` before, the dropdown menu disappears. I don't want the dropdown to disappear, I just want it to say "no power" when it is null and I should be able to change it from `null` to something.

hero-detail.component.html

```
<form #heroUpdateForm = "ngForm">
      {{diagnostic}}
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name"
               required
               *ngIf="hero" [(ngModel)]="hero.name" name="name">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="desc">Description</label>
        <input type="text"  class="form-control" id="desc"
              *ngIf="hero" [(ngModel)]="hero.desc" name="desc">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group" *ngIf="hero?.power">
        <label for="power">Main Power</label>
        <select class="form-control"  id="power"
                required
                [(ngModel)]="hero.mainPower" name="power">
          <option [ngValue]="null">no power</option>
          <ng-container *ngFor="let power of powers">
            <option [value]="power.id">{{power.name}}</option>
          </ng-container>
        </select>
      </div>
    </form>
```

hero-detail.component.ts

```
export class HeroDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  public heroes: Hero[];
  public powers: Power[];
  submitted = false;
  private hero: Hero;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private heroService: HeroService,
    private powerService: PowerService,
    private location: Location,
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getHero();
    this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = () => false;
    this.getHeroes();
    this.getPowers();
  }

  getHero(): void{
    const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.heroService.getHero(id).subscribe(
      (hero: Hero) => {
        this.hero = hero;
        if (hero.power != null) {
          this.powerService.getPowerById(hero.power).subscribe(
            (powerResponse) => {
              hero.power = powerResponse;
            }
          );
        }
      });
  }
  public getHeroes(): void {
    this.heroService.getHeroes().subscribe(
      (response: Hero[]) => {
        this.hero = response;
        },
      (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        alert(error.message);
      }
    );
  }

  public getPowers(): void {
    this.powerService.getAllPowers().subscribe(
      (response: Power[]) => {
        this.power = response;
      },
      (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        alert(error.message);
      }
    );
  }

  goBack(): void {
    this.location.back();
  }

  save(): void {
    this.heroService.updateHero(this.hero, this.hero.id)
      .subscribe(() => this.goBack());
  }
  onSubmit() {this.submitted = true;}

  get diagnostic() {return JSON.stringify(this.hero);}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is obvious why it'll disappear, look at your template again:

```
       <div class="form-group" *ngIf="hero?.power"> <!-- lookie here, if either hero or power is null this element along with everything in it will be gone!! -->
         <label for="power">Main Power</label>
         <select class="form-control"  id="power"    <!-- your select is inside the div above with the ng if -->
                required
                [(ngModel)]="hero.mainPower" name="power">
         <option [ngValue]="null">no power</option>
         <ng-container *ngFor="let power of powers">
           <option [value]="power.id">{{power.name}}</option>
         </ng-container>
       </select>
```

essentially the ngIf you have in the div surrounding the select element says the following:

- if(`ngIf`) hero and power -> display element
- if(`ngIf`) no hero and power -> remove element

You might not want to have `*ngIf="hero?.power"` perhaps you should just check if there is a hero `*ngIf="hero"` instead

Comment: I understood eventually, but didn't what to check with. If I did no check I get a TypeError Cannot read undefined, but now it works. Thank you!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help, perhaps a better solution would be to have `ngIf="hero"`  and change your ngFor to be `<ng-container *ngFor="let power of getPowers(hero)">` and return an empty array of options if hero has no powers, the check for power would be in `getPowers`.